# Arduino: avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "/dev/ttyACM1": Input/output error

Tags: arch-linux, usb, tty, serial-port, arduino

I use arduino ide on arch linux with arduino uno connected via USB.
I am sure that I choosed right port and board in ide menu.

when I run `ls -l /dev/ttyACM*` I get:

```
crw-rw---- 1 root uucp 166, 0 14. dub 12.44 /dev/ttyACM0
crw-rw-rw- 1 root uucp 166, 1 14. dub 12.54 /dev/ttyACM1
```

but when I click upload I get this error:

```
Sketch uses 440 bytes (1%) of program storage space. Maximum is 32256 bytes.
Global variables use 9 bytes (0%) of dynamic memory, leaving 2039 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2048 bytes.

avrdude: Version 6.3, compiled on Jul  7 2020 at 19:38:43
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "//etc/avrdude.conf"
         User configuration file is "/home/john/.avrduderc"
         User configuration file does not exist or is not a regular file, skipping

         Using Port                    : /dev/ttyACM1
         Using Programmer              : arduino
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 115200
avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "/dev/ttyACM1": Input/output error

avrdude done.  Thank you.

the selected serial port 
 does not exist or your board is not connected
```

Error remains on newest linux kernel and LTS.

---

My device is Lenovo thinkpad X390: Linux 5.11.14-arch1-1

---

When I plug arduino to usb and then run `sudo dmesg` I get this messages:

```
[ 1605.378324] usb 1-4: new full-speed USB device number 14 using xhci_hcd
[ 1605.520509] usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=2341, idProduct=0043, bcdDevice= 0.01
[ 1605.520517] usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=220
[ 1605.520521] usb 1-4: Manufacturer: Arduino (www.arduino.cc)
[ 1605.520523] usb 1-4: SerialNumber: 7583434383935150E152
[ 1605.523881] cdc_acm 1-4:1.0: ttyACM1: USB ACM device
[ 1630.618749] usb 1-9: reset full-speed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
[ 1630.792727] audit: type=1130 audit(1618567069.016:82): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=fprintd comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
[ 1632.601215] audit: type=1100 audit(1618567070.822:83): pid=29714 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=1 msg='op=PAM:authentication grantors=? acct="john" exe="/usr/bin/sudo" hostname=? addr=? terminal=/dev/pts/1 res=failed'
[ 1635.720577] audit: type=1100 audit(1618567073.942:84): pid=29714 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=1 msg='op=PAM:authentication grantors=pam_faillock,pam_permit,pam_faillock acct="john" exe="/usr/bin/sudo" hostname=? addr=? terminal=/dev/pts/1 res=success'
[ 1635.721507] audit: type=1101 audit(1618567073.942:85): pid=29714 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=1 msg='op=PAM:accounting grantors=pam_unix,pam_permit,pam_time acct="john" exe="/usr/bin/sudo" hostname=? addr=? terminal=/dev/pts/1 res=success'
[ 1635.722751] audit: type=1110 audit(1618567073.946:86): pid=29714 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=1 msg='op=PAM:setcred grantors=pam_faillock,pam_permit,pam_faillock acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/sudo" hostname=? addr=? terminal=/dev/pts/1 res=success'
[ 1635.727018] audit: type=1105 audit(1618567073.949:87): pid=29714 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=1 msg='op=PAM:session_open grantors=pam_limits,pam_unix,pam_permit acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/sudo" hostname=? addr=? terminal=/dev/pts/1 res=success'
```

---

How can I fix this ?
Thank you for help

**PS:** If you need any more information, comment below and I will add it soon as possible.

Comment: What are you typing on the LInux side to start avrude? If it's a USB device, shouldn't it be opening /dev/ttyUSB0 - or some other number then 0? Try it with "-p usb" or without anything specifying the ports.

Comment: @CinaedSimson I am not starting avrude by my self. I just click upload in arduino IDE.

Comment: But there should be config file in the directory where you installed the software. In any case, unplug the arduino uno from the unknown hardware running arch linux, then plug it back in. Type "dmesg" and then near the bottom of the output should be the device name that your arch linux system sees the uno as - which should probably  contain the words "uart"  and "usb".

Comment: @CinaedSimson I added `dmesg` output to question. I installed arudino package using pacman.

Comment: See: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=122180
Try to run cmd as `sudo`

Comment: @ofirule I tried that and got the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and the only fix that helped me was to disable the usb auto suspend inside the grub config.

After disabling it I could use my arduino board fine.

So I did:

1. `sudo vim /etc/default/grub`
2. search this line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""` (it may be already filled with different stuff inside the quotation marks)
3. change it to contain `usbcore.autosuspend=-1` somewhere inside the quotes
4. run `sudo update-grub`
5. and then reboot

This helped me because I realized after a lot of googling that the problem was actually that the arduino reconnected whenever I tried to use it. So when using minicom to access the serial output the arduino was disconnected and connected again immediately. I only noticed it when using
`watch -n 1 ' sudo dmesg | tail -n 20'`
to see what happens when running minicom.

This behavior should change after disabling autosuspend inside grub.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I do not use grub and do not have it even installed. I use systemdboot.

Comment: The tlp answer below solved this for me, but the diagnostic steps tailing dmesg was useful to show it was the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

A solution sourced [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/mqovt5/arduino_avrdude_ser_open_cant_open_device/gw3ji54/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) that worked for me:

> I was doing some more testings and got to another working solution for me. Do you, by any chance, have `tlp` installed and enabled?
>
> Apparently there is this thing called usb autosuspend and tlp enables it by default (which might be sensible). All I did was to edit the file `/etc/tlp.conf` and change `#USB_AUTOSUSPEND=1` -> `USB_AUTOSUSPEND=0`. After a reboot I was able to upload to the arduino, even on the latest kernel 5.11.16.
>
> I was trying to disable the autosuspend via udev rules but I couldn't do it. I'm thinking that maybe `tlp` configuration takes precedence over udev rules although I'm not sure at all.

Comment: I am using tlp, had the same problem, and this solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the latest Manjaro updates somehow caused the **cdc_acm** module to break.. In order to fix this issue, I ran the following commands:

1. `sudo modprobe -r cdc_acm`
2. `sudo modprobe cdc_acm`
3. `sudo chmod 666 /dev/ttyACM0`

Comment: I did what you suggested and issue still remains. Still thank you for answer.

Comment: It's just a temporary fix until a permanent fix will be provided.. do the modprobe remove-install steps and right after that try to upload the sketch, need to be fast, there is some sort of a race bug in this cdc_acm driver.